# instances of singleton array objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, singleton

I have implemented an array with the singleton method like this:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface globaltextarray : NSObject 
+(NSMutableArray*)Text;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "globaltextarray.h"

@implementation globaltextarray

+(NSMutableArray*)Text {
    static NSMutableArray *statArray;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        statArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    });
    return statArray;
}
@end
```

I use it in one of the forms i have and works perfectly. What i want to achieve is the following.

At the form that i use this globalarray when i tap on a button a new form opens same as the one i had already opened before but data inside of it differ then on the second form that just opened i tap a button and the same story goes on. So my question is this: Is there a way to create multiple singleton arrays using this one and only globaltextarray object which should hold different data that show up as the user navigates from one form to another (the second, third etc) ?

Hope you understood it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why would you make a singleton array if you could just use a backing iVar?  You're incurring an unnecessary overhead here.

Comment: Thanks for responding...Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First better to read about [how-and-when-to-use-singleton-classes and var's](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2008/04/20/how-and-when-to-use-singleton-classes/).

For achieving your functionality, please don't use singleton array.

You can do 2 things.

**first way is**, create a property of `NSMutableArray` for your each form and fill it their own view load methods.

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *formDetailsArray
```

**Second way is a worst case**, create a global `NSMutableArray` property for your parent form and access it in your child forms.

**Parent form**

```
 @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *formParentArray;

[formParentArray addObject:form1childArray];
[formParentArray addObject:form2childArray];
[formParentArray addObject:form3childArray];
[formParentArray addObject:form4childArray];
```

**Child1 form**

```
datasource = parentFormObj.form1childArray
```

**Child2 form**

```
datasource = parentFormObj.form2childArray
```